# Use XSLT to generate XSLT, namespace prefix

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to use XSLT to transform an XML into another XSLT. In the output XSLT, the namespace prefix and uri should be decided by the XML document. For example, the XML document is

```
<namespaces>
    <namespace>
       <prefix>abc</prefix>
       <uri>my.domain.abc</uri>
    </namespace>
    <namespace>
       <prefix>def</prefix>
       <uri>my.domain.def</uri>
    </namespace>
</namespaces>
```

And the output XSLT should be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:abc="my.domain.abc"
    xmlns:def="my.domain.def"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I tried this way, it didn't work:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:axsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/TransformAlias">
    <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="axsl" result-prefix="xsl"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <axsl:stylesheet 
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
            version="2.0">
        <xsl:for-each select="/namespaces/namespace">
          <xsl:namespace name="{prefix}" select="uri"/>
        </xsl:for-each>    
      </axsl:stylesheet>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The error is `prefix: Missing context item`. Any thought how to achieve this?

Comment: The XSLT snippet lacks a `version` attribute on `xsl:stylesheet`, after fixing that the sample http://xsltransform.net/6r5Gh3j does work for me. The error you get sounds as if you have not provided an input document or have some code working with atomic values or in a function where not context item is defined. So how does a minimal but complete sample allowing us to reproduce the problem look?

Comment: Which XSLT processor do you use?

Comment: @MathiasMüller This is the actual message. Note that the "prefix" is the prefix in my xslt <xsl:namespace name="{prefix}" select="uri">

Comment: @mattsun, which XSLT processor do you use that gives that error message?

Comment: @mattsun You're right of course, I did not read very thoroughly. I have deleted my nonsense comment. Do you show the whole stylesheet you are using or did you simplify it before posting here?